# Add custom CA certificate to Ubuntu 20.04 works fine, but fails on Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, certificates

I went through the process of adding a new CA certificate on Ubuntu (20.04), but the same steps did not work on Debian (10)
in both environments, I have downloaded the custom CA certificate (via firefox `about:certificate` page for an untrusted certificate site) as a PEM, then I converted it to the CRT format using openssl and then I called `update-ca-certificates`.

Here are the steps in a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y curl openssl ca-certificates
COPY src/main/docker/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem /root/
RUN openssl x509 -in /root/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem -inform PEM -out /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom-root-ca.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN curl https://nexus-using-custom-cert.custom.org
```

Building this Dockerfile

```
docker build . --no-cache
```

would output:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 9140108b62dc
Step 2/6 : RUN apt update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y curl openssl ca-certificates
 ---> Running in 2fd506a9b619
[install stuff]
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20190110ubuntu1.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Removing intermediate container 2fd506a9b619
 ---> 57c01aa6180d
Step 3/6 : COPY src/main/docker/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem /root/
 ---> e0aa6a44ced1
Step 4/6 : RUN openssl x509 -in /root/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem -inform PEM -out /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom-root-ca.crt
 ---> Running in 70746b6e16fe
Removing intermediate container 70746b6e16fe
 ---> de9c98488bde
Step 5/6 : RUN update-ca-certificates
 ---> Running in 1137779ed67f
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Removing intermediate container 1137779ed67f
 ---> c834167a52a3
Step 6/6 : RUN curl https://nexus-using-custom-cert.custom.org
 ---> Running in a8dc2aa55993
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<html>

<body> stuff
</body>
</html>
100   470  100   470    0     0   1492      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1487
Removing intermediate container a8dc2aa55993
 ---> 809e4e5b6ac1
Successfully built 809e4e5b6ac1
```

BUT, if I use `debian:10` instead (no other changes to the `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM debian:10
```

and I rebuild the Docker image:

Building this Dockerfile

```
docker build . --no-cache
```

would output:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM debian:10
 ---> f6dcff9b59af
Step 2/6 : RUN apt update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y curl openssl ca-certificates
 ---> Running in 15d0c69448ed
[install stuff]
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20200601~deb10u1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Removing intermediate container 15d0c69448ed
 ---> 4bcfe8b5074b
Step 3/6 : COPY src/main/docker/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem /root/
 ---> fa53734a536a
Step 4/6 : RUN openssl x509 -in /root/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem -inform PEM -out /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom-root-ca.crt
 ---> Running in b86813e50a77
Removing intermediate container b86813e50a77
 ---> 0b0e6aa67d7d
Step 5/6 : RUN update-ca-certificates
 ---> Running in c18625c31424
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Removing intermediate container c18625c31424
 ---> 559636874009
Step 6/6 : RUN curl https://nexus-using-custom-cert.custom.org
 ---> Running in fcd2e16441fd
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
The command '/bin/sh -c curl https://nexus-using-custom-cert.custom.org' returned a non-zero code: 60
```

So, what should I do to add a custom ca certificate to `Debian 10` ? Debian `update-ca-certificates` documentation is pretty similar to `Ubuntu` doc; what's wrong ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: few colleagues of mine have suggested that I add a `chmod 644` on the cert before running `update-ca-certificates` : `RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom-root-ca.crt`
but that did not change a thing:

Comment: Another colleague suggested I do not convert the format of the certificate authority chain, directly copying it to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` : `COPY src/main/docker/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` but that did not change the Debian situation either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to my colleague @BrettDG, I was able to make it work under Debian as well.

**TLDR** : Make sure you include individually all certificates in the chain of trust, Ubuntu can be satisfied with only the intermediates, Debian will require the full chain

The website I am connecting to has the following chain of trust:

```
MyOrgRootCA
|-> MyOrgIntermediateCA
    |-> Website
```

and while I was thinking my PEM file named `nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem` had the full chain, well a run of:

```
openssl x509 -in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/nexus-custom-ca-chain.pem -noout -text
```

eventually showed that I only had the site certificate and the intermediary certificate in this chain -  **so the root certificate was missing**

Also, not sure it's a good idea to have several certs in 1 file; try to split them individually in their own file.

Here is the Dockerfile that will work on Debian AND Ubuntu

```
# FROM ubuntu:20:04
FROM debian:10
RUN apt update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y curl openssl ca-certificates
COPY root.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.pem
COPY intermediate.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/intermediate.pem
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/intermediate.pem
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN curl https://nexus-using-custom-cert.custom.org
```

**Lesson learned** : Verify the chain of trust and provide each and every certificate along the chain

On each certificate in the chain, run the `openssl x509 -noout` output and look for:

```
MyOrgRootCA
Issuer:  C = CA, ST = Quebec, L = Montreal, O = Org, OU = tools, CN = Org ROOT CA
Subject: C = CA, ST = Quebec, L = Montreal, O = Org, OU = tools, CN = Org ROOT CA
```

```
MyOrgIntermediateCA
Issuer:  C = CA, ST = Quebec, L = Montreal, O = Org, OU = tools, CN = Org ROOT CA
Subject: C = CA, ST = Quebec, L = Montreal, O = Org, OU = tools, CN = Intermediate ROOT CA
```

There, if when we `curl -v` our website and see:

```
issuer: C = CA, ST = Quebec, L = Montreal, O = Org, OU = tools, CN = Intermediate ROOT CA
```

We know that providing the Intermediate and Root certificate, we're golden.

**Useful command lines**

Look in detail into your certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -noout -text
```

Convert from binary (DER) format to x509 PEM (as wanted by `update-ca-certificates`)

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.crt  -inform der -outform PEM -out mycert.crt
```

Convert from text (PEM) format to binary (as wanted by Java Keytool)

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.pem -outform der -out mycert.der
```

Comment: Java `keytool` supports both PEM and binary (= OpenSSL DER) files for certificates, although before j7 (2011) it didn't handle PEM _with 'comment' lines preceding the actual PEM block_ which some software produces, and Windows also tends to insert a 'BOM' at the beginning of text files which breaks the PEM formatting and must be removed

Comment: yes that's correct, I checked it with JDK 11, thanks for the precision !